# C Programming - Pointers (with increments)

Tags: c, pointers, increment

```
int main()
{
    int x = 30, *y, *z;
    y = &x; 
    /* Assume address of x is 500 and integer is 4 byte size */
    z = y;
    *y++ = *z++;
    x++;
    printf("x=%d, y=%d, z=%d\n", x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

The above is the code. 
The output is: `x=31, y=504, z=504`

Please correct me if I'm wrong:

From what I understand: `y=&x;` assigns the address of `x` to `y`. So, `y` now holds the value of `500`.

`z=y;` Since `y = 500`, this assigns `500` to `z`.

What really confuses me is this part `*y++=*z++;`, I don't exactly know what this means as there's many things going on at the same time. `z` gets incremented and pointed to somewhere (AND where is it pointing actually? There is no address assigned to it like y i.e `y=&x;`. Then `*y` also gets incremented at the same time (are you even allowed to do that?).

Another thing that confuses me is that: in my opinion, since `y` points to `x`, when `y++` happens, `x` should be incremented to `31`, and then when going down the code block `x++` happens, `x` should now be `32`.

So, question is, how did we get that output of `x=31, y=504, z=504`? Thank you.

Comment: `printf("x=%d, y=%d, z=%d\n", x, y, z);` is undefined behavior. If you absolutely have to, use `%p` to print pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between \*y++ and ++\*y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978286/difference-between-y-and-y)

Comment: @Evert Yes, it is for an exercise. I'm trying to understand the output.

Comment: @JosefHoppe from the UB.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya as in `printf("x=%d, y=%p, z=%p\n", x, y, z);` ?

Comment: `*y++=*z++` is also undefined behavior since you are performing pointer arithmetic on non array pointers

Comment: `y` is not 500, it is the address of `x`. Also, it most probably isn't 500 or anything such, use `%p` for pointers.

Comment: @JosefHoppe Apologies. It is assumed. Edited the question (added comment) `/* Assume address of x is 500 and integer is 4 byte size */`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya how's that dereferencing an invalid pointer?

Comment: in any case `%d` doesn't work with pointers, you must use `%p` with a `(void*)` cast.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala not only your case, the _correct_ case. :)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I misread the expression. I edited my comment and removed the second point.

Comment: What does [**C Operator Precedence**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) tell you should happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down.

- `int x=30, *y, *z;` `y,z` are defined and `x` is initialized.
- `y=&x; z=y;` both of the pointers are assigned with the address of x (i.e. `&x`)
- `*y++=*z++;` This one contains a few things, so I'll split it up:

---

1. According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) the `postfix++` takes precedence over `indirection*` so we can look at `*y++` as `*(y++)`
2. `y++` means that the value of y will be incremented by 1 and since `y` is `int*` it will actually add `sizeof(int)` to it's value [4 in your case]. **But** the value of the expression `y++` is the value of `y` **before** the increment, which leads us to...
3. indirection: after the `postfix++` is done, the indirection is evaluated and since `y++`'s value is the value of "old" `y` you get the value of `x`

Conclusion: `y` was incremented by `1` but the indirection (dereference) led us to x.

The same applies to `z`. Eventually what happens is that both `y,z` are incremented, but **before** that the value in x is assigned to x (obsolete :) )

Next you'll have `x++;` which increments the value of `x` by 1. And that's it.

You can think of `*y++=*z++;` as:

1. `*y = *z;`
2. `y++, z++;`

Comment: The value 500 is assumed, as this is a practice exercise. `/* Assume address of x is 500 and integer is 4 byte size */`

Comment: What if it's a prefix? Like `*++*y`. Any changes to the output?

Comment: @WCKennedays, you mean `*++y`? then it is UB because the pointer `y+1` is not necessarily valid.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya sorry, I mean `++*y`

Comment: @WCKennedays then you mean `++*y = ++*z`? that is again UB because you are writing to the same pointer twice between 2 sequence points.

Comment: [**C11 Standard (draft n1570)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) *§ 6.5 (2) of Expressions* is your reference

Comment: @CIsForCookies _'Since postfix++ takes precedence over *'_ It does not - first value of the *p is taken, then p is incremented so you can : `while(*p) putch(*p++);`

Comment: @PeterJ but http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence states that postfix precedes indirection. Is it wrong?

Comment: @CIsForCookies but expressions are evaluated from the left to the right - so the first is *p then p++.

Comment: @PeterJ OK, My mistake. Thx!!

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Big help.