# C: Trouble understanding pointers in the while loop of this code

Tags: c, pointers

I'm using a debugger to read through this code, and I'm a little confused by `while ((*d++ = *s2++));` - in the debugger variables, d seems to shorten after each loop (goes from `'Hello hello'` to `'ello hello'` while `s1` changes to `'cello hello'`). What is the while loop looping through (shouldn't it be `while(condition); do(something))`?

Why aren't the variable values of d and s1 the same (isn't d is a pointer to s1)? And when they return to the main function, is `curdst` = the pointer of `dst`?

```
/*    
  Input: char pointers for source (s2) and destination (s1)

  Output: returns the pointer to the destination (s1)
*/

char *my_strcpy(char * , const char * );

int main()
{

  char src[] = "cs23!";
  char dst[]="Hello hello";
  char *curdst;
  int len=0;

  while(src[len++]);

  // do the copy

  curdst= my_strcpy(dst, src);

  // check to see if the NULL char is copied too.

  printf("dst array %s and last element %d\n", dst, atoi(&dst[len]));

  return 0;

}

char *my_strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2) {

  register char *d = s1;

  // print the pointer variables address and their contents, and first char

  printf("s2 address %p, its contents is a pointer %p to first char %c \n", (void *)&s2, (void *)s2, *s2);
  printf("s1 address %p, its contents is a pointer %p to first char %c \n", (void *)&s1, (void *)s1, *s1);

  while ((*d++ = *s2++));
  return(s1);

}
```

Comment: Note that `*d++ = *s2++` is very different from `*d++ == *s2++`. Here, you're overwriting the values in `*d` with values from `*s2`, until you reach the null terminator in `s2`.

Comment: The condition here is that the `*s2` is other than zero (string null-terminator).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20957532/2201041) for a breakdown of a similar thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather typical didactic implementation of `strcpy()`. It works like this:

- `my_strcpy()` takes two arguments. The first argument is a pointer to the first element of a destination character array. The second argument is a pointer to the first element of a source character string, that is, a character array terminated by a `NUL` (aka `\0`) character. The function copies the characters from the source string to the destination buffer, including the `NUL` terminator, and returns a pointer to the first element of the destination buffer.

  ```
  char *my_strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2) {
  ```
- First things first, make a copy of the first argument, because we need to return it after the copying is done.

  ```
  char *d = s1;
  ```
- Then, copy the characters; this is done in a tight loop, working like this:

  - Copy the current character `* s2` to the place pointed to by `d`, as if executing `* d = * s2`; then
  - Increment `d` to point to the next place in the destination buffer as if executing `d++` and increment `s2` to point to the next character to be copied as if executing `s2++`; and
  - Exit the loop if the last character which was copied was `NUL`.

  This is written in a very concise manner:

  ```
  while (* d++ = * s2++);
  ```

  `* s2++` means "take the character pointed to by `s2` then increment `s2`". Similarily, `* d++` as a left-hand value means "use the variable pointed to by `d` then increment `d`". The order of precedence of operators helps dispense with parentheses because `++` has higher priority than `*` which has higher priority than `=`. The value of the assignment is the assigned value, so the loop ends when the assigned character has the value 0.
- Finally, return `s1`, which was not changed by the function.

  ```
  return s1;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you!! Is changing `*d` changing `s1` so that when you return `s1`, you have copied s2 to s1?

Comment: @helloworld: You have copied the character string to which `s2` points into the buffer to which `s1` points.