# For-loop in C language, for (i = len; i--;)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Why the loop stops when i = -1?

```
for (i = len; i--;)
```

Full code is here http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#C .

Thx!!

Comment: What does the second part of a for loop do, and what does i-- mean?  Answer those, and you've got your answer.

Comment: The loop stops at i==0, however i-- decrements the value once _after_ it has been compared and the loop has decided to exit, making i end up at the value -1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The loop stops when the value of `i--` is `0`. Since `i--` returns the value before the decrement, when `i--` is `0`, `i` is `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an answer worthy of being right, though Joachim Isaksson's comment is a concise explanation.

The loop stops when it evaluates a value of 0 or false.

The `i--` is what's throwing you off.  That's "post-decrement", i.e. the operator returns the current value of i (in this case, for the loop to evaluate), and immediately thereafter, decrements the current value.  Pseudocode for postdecrement follows:

```
int retval = i;
i = i - 1;
return retval;
```

(Based on Eric Lippert's comments, technically, the compiler could do postdecrement as `i = i - 1; return i + 1;`.  The point is that the value emitted by the operator is no longer the value of `i`.)

(as opposed to predecrement, which in pseudocode is simply):

```
i = i - 1;
return i;
```

So when the loop is evaluating `i`, it sees 0 so exits, but immediately after evaluating the operator has decremented `i` to -1.

So, to answer your question:

The loop doesn't stop when i = -1.  It stops when i = 0, but then i is decremented to -1.

Comment: I note that the pre-decrement *also* evaluates `i` and then after evaluation, decrements it. If you think that's false then ask yourself the question: *how could the new value be computed without first evaluating the old value*? The difference between the pre- and post- operators is not *when `i` is evaluated relative to the mutation*. Rather it is *what the value of the operator is*.

Comment: @EricLippert I think the issue you took was with my use of the word "evaluate", which was sloppy.  The for loop evaluates the value returned by the operator.  I made an edit and included pseudocode.  Does that fit better?

Comment: My point was rather nit-picky, I admit. But I see a *lot* of misconceptions about this operator. I note that your pseudo-code might imply an ordering of side effects which would be warrented in C# or Java but not in C. C promises you that the value of the operator will be either the new or the old value, but does not promise you *when the mutation will happen*, just that it will happen sometime before the next sequence point.

Comment: A more detailed exegesis of the various situations you can get into can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926794/incrementing-pointers-exact-sequence/17935062#17935062

Comment: Thanks, that was an interesting (and well written) read.  I keep forgetting about how loose the rules are for C compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop stops when the expression `i--` becomes `0` because any non-zero value in C is treated as `true` and a zero as `false`.
At each iteration `i` is checked for `true` or `false` and then  decremented .

Comment: Thx, this is such a simple thing that does not always come to mind.

Comment: Rather **(1)** checked for `true` or `false`, then **(2)** decremented. So, I don't know, if I'm not missing something, this answer is almost wrong...

Comment: @ThoAppelsin; That was typo.

Comment: @haccks That's not what [**typo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typo) means, but whatever...

Comment: @ThoAppelsin; You can say this type of error occurs when you try to answer first :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (i = len; i--;)
```

Here `i--` is the exit condition. When `i--` is false which is 0 the loop will exit.

Since `i--` is post decrement, `i` value is used for condition checking. So when

```
i=0;
```

loop exits after that `i=i-1` is executed as part of post decrement so

```
i=-1;
```

when loop exits since first `i's` value is used after that it is decremented

Answer (score 0):

FOR loops are composed of 3 parts:

for ( [**Initialization**] ; [**Exit Condition**] ; [**Cycle Update**] )

[**Initialization**] is used to assign a value to the loop index before the first iteration

[**Exit Condition**] is a boolean expression evaluated before each iteration. If it is true another iteration is executed, otherwise the FOR loop ends

[**Cycle Update**] is the instruction used to update the loop index at each iteration

a classical FOR statement looks like this:

FOR(I = len ; I > END_VALUE ; I--)

What is probably missing in your code is the exit condition, so the cycle update part is interpreted as an exit condition and consequently treated as a boolean expression. When the integer becomes 0 its interpreted boolean value corresponds to FALSE and the loop is ended. Any non-zero value is instead interpreted as  a TRUE boolean and allows the execution of another iteration.

Answer (score -1):

When a boolean value is needed, `0` is same as false. Anything other than `0` is true. So, it must stop when `i` is `0`, not `-1`. You are seeing the value of `i` to be `-1` because of the post-decrement operator.